# OpenCV installed but still not found when importing it

Tags: python, opencv, nvidia-jetson

Good afternoon everyone,

I tried many solutions from other people, but nothing is working.
I have downloaded OpenCV, but everytime I run the code it says there is no opencv2 on my computer.
And maybe it is important, I am using a Jetson TX2 with Ubuntu 16.04.
Here is the error:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/imutils/convenience.py", line 6, in 
    import cv2

ImportError: No module named 'cv2'

In this source, I have the folder 'opencv-3.4.9'

```
import numpy as np
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages')
import cv2
```

...

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu, you can try **`sudo apt-get install python-opencv`** to install opencv from pre-built binaries.

Or, you can also visit [opencv on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV) for alternative installation instructions.

Comment: Still doesnt work, it said many times in the terminal '...is not a symbolic link'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a virtual environment I strongly recommend [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/) tutorial. If you are trying to install OpenCV systemwide then;

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-opencv
sudo apt-get install python3-opencv
```

but above code won't install the latest version.
For the latest version you could take a look at [this](https://github.com/mdegans/nano_build_opencv) github repo.

I had a jetson nano and it gave me all sorts of trouble about OpenCV. Therefore I recommend the use of virtual environments for these kind of situations. It may take a while to build the libraries in jetson but it is the best-practice.

Best of luck.